# iOS-Charts - cannot hide Y axis

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am trying to hide all of the lines that iOS-Charts displays. However there is one line that I cannot hide. I have searched through the docs but could not find an answer.

```
                let data = LineChartData()
                let ds = LineChartDataSet(entries: yValues, label: "Day")
                ds.setColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0))
                ds.setCircleColor(.white)
                ds.circleRadius = 5
                ds.lineWidth = 3
                ds.valueFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 6, weight: .bold)

                ds.valueColors = [#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)]
                data.addDataSet(ds)
                cell.averageTempChartView.data = data

            }else{
                cell.averageTempLabel.text = ""
            }

            cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
            cell.cellView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cell.cellView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.23
            cell.cellView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
            cell.cellView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            cell.cellView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            cell.cellView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.7843137255, blue: 0.2039215686, alpha: 1)

            cell.averageTempChartView.xAxis.wordWrapEnabled = true
            cell.averageTempChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom
            cell.averageTempChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            cell.averageTempChartView.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .bold)
            cell.averageTempChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
            cell.averageTempChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
            cell.averageTempChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
            cell.averageTempChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
            cell.averageTempChartView.leftAxis.gridColor = .clear
            cell.averageTempChartView.rightAxis.gridColor = .clear

            cell.averageTempChartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
            cell.averageTempChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
            cell.averageTempChartView.noDataText = ""
            cell.averageTempChartView.legend.enabled = false
            cell.averageTempChartView.noDataFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
            cell.averageTempChartView.noDataTextColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```

[image]
Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think you need `cell.averageTempChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false`

Answer (score 1):

You already used the right property `drawAxisLineEnabled` for `xAxis`, so just use the same property for leftAxis.

`cell.averageTempChartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false`